# How to convert 2 restricted decimal variables to a third variable and vice versa?

Tags: c#, algorithm, decimal, rounding

I have 2 convertor methods as below:

```
private const decimal MaxValidValue = 99.99m;
public decimal ConvertABToC(decimal a, decimal b)
{
    return a * b;
}

public void ConvertCtoAB(decimal c, ref decimal a, ref decimal b)
{
    if (c > MaxValidValue*MaxValidValue)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }

    if (c <= MaxValidValue)
    {
        a = 1.00m;
        b = c;
    }
    else 
    {
        // need to introduce some logic or assumptions here
    }
}
```

There are 3 important things to know:

1) The a and b variables are in the range of 0.00 to 99.99 therefore c can't have a value greater than 99.99*99.99

2) the a, b and c must not have more than 2 decimal precession e.g. a = 99.123 would be invalid.

3) you can use rounding if you'd need to as long as decimal.Round(a * b, 2) == c.

4) combinations like (1, 3), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 4), (0.5, 8) or even (0.25, 16) are all valid; it doesn't matter as long as c would be the product of a and b.

How would you complete the implementation of ConvertCtoAB?

Many thanks,

Comment: Once you have converted it to `c`, there is no way of getting back to the same `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Femaref: Well, there is the case when c = 99.99 * 99.99, but other than that... yeah.

Comment: Put another way, if you have `a` and `b` of 1.5 and 2 or 1 and 3, `c` is 3. If `c` is 3, `a` and `b` can be anything, unless there are rules you are not telling us about. The precision of the data type and the number of decimal places aside, `c` is the product of an infinite number of `a` and `b` combinations.

Comment: Do A and B need to be returned their original values or do they just have to have valid values? for example if you had C=120, would 60*2 and 30*4 both be valid solutions?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, yes you're right; we should be introducing some rules. not sure what exactly.

Comment: @deepee1, it'd need to return its original value.

Comment: @William, we can't just go and introduce arbitrary rules for you! Either you have a business rule (or set of rules) for this scenario where `a` and `b` *can* be deduced from a given `c`, or you do not. Is this an actual business problem you are facing? Or is there a business problem you face that you trying to use *this* as a solution?

Comment: @William: Your "therefore" in the first rule has come out of nowhere. What's introduced this restriction?

Comment: I assume you're asking for our definition of a bijective function f : A x A -> A, where A = [0.00 ... 99.99], and max(f) = 99.99 * 99.99?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, it's a business problem and an interview question!

Comment: @William: It doesn't *sound* like a real business problem - especially when you keep changing the rules, and giving *contradictory* rules.

Comment: it is a real business problem. rule #4 was missing and added; nothing else changed.

Comment: @William: As specified in my answer, rule 4 sounds like it would be better expressed as `a <= b` always holds...

Comment: @William, you've changed the rules again. So it is a must that c = a * b? Were you actually asked this question and given these requirements in an interview? Again, this question is unsolvable given these constraints.

Comment: @William: Well now you've changed rule 3, it becomes *obviously* impossible. See my edited answer.

Comment: not true. it's possible.

Comment: @William: Your question is *still* unclear - but you certainly *can't* get back to the same `a` and `b` values after multiplication, even if you deem the order to be irrelevant - c=4 could be from (a,b)=(2, 2), or (1, 4), or (0.5, 8), or (0.25, 16). You still haven't specified anything about what sort of invertibility is required, and you haven't said how you're meant to deal with the case where multiplying `a` by `b` to get `c` gives you a value with more than 2 decimal places. Either you're describing the requirements incredibly poorly, or they're impossible. Or both.

Comment: (2, 2), or (1, 4), or (0.5, 8), or (0.25, 16) are all valid values Jon. please read again rule #4; hope it's clear.

Comment: @William: No, it's not clear - because the example you've chosen makes it look like you don't care about the *ordering* - if you'd given (1, 3) and (2, 1.5) that would have been clearer. See my updated answer - it would still help if you'd clarify the question. It sounds like you only really need *one* conversion routine, given that the conversion for `c` is predefined - and it can't cope with all possible values of `c` anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply `C` by 10,000. Then factor this number into its prime factors. Then find a partition of the prime factors into two sets such that the product of the numbers in each set is less than 10,000. If such a partition can be found, then return these two products divided by 100 as `A` and `B`. Otherwise, add one to the number and try again.

For example, if `C=100.07`, then the factors are `2, 2, 5, 5, 10007`. Because one of the products must include the factor `10007`, which is a prime number, the first condition can never be satisfied. So we try again with `1000701 = 3*3*3*13*2851`. This time, we can partition the number, and we have `A=3.51` and `B=28.51` as a possible solution.

You can do this at most 99 times. If you need 100 or more, than the input value cannot have been generated from `ConvertABToC`.

This only guarantees that the result of `ConvertCtoAB`, when fed back into `ConvertABtoC` will produce the same `C`, not the other way around. It appears to violate rule #3, but then elsewhere the question is about rounding.

If no rounding at all is allowed, then one should stop and report infeasibility after trying the original 10000*C.

Comment: you're genius! why/how did you add one to the number in this scenario?

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of `c` potentially violating rule 2, as specified in my answer. It's also not clear whether reversibility *is* important or not - it was in one of the versions of the question, but pinning down the requirements here is like trying to herd cats. I *hope* it was clearer than this in the interview...

Comment: reversibility is not important in the sense that both (1, 3) and (3, 1) are acceptable if that's what you mean Jon. why it potentially violates rule 2? it suggests using prime numbers which makes sense.

Comment: @William: I mean more than that - are you happy with *any* factors? So are (2, 2), (0.5, 8) etc *also* acceptable? This isn't just about reversing pair - it's about finding *all* possible pairs of factors. As for violating rule 2 - you can't have `a` and `b` with values 0.01, for example, as then `c = a * b` (rule 3) violates rule 2 (c would be 0.00001, so more than 2dp).

Comment: yes, please read rule #4. what I'm not sure about Jeffrey's solution is how he's added the 01 to the right of the number and if this repeats for e.g. 5-10 times the number becomes so huge.

Comment: if c <= 99.99, then a = 1 and b = c and it would work. please refer to the question.

Comment: so you meant c * 10000 + 1! how would you get rid of that 1 at the end? otherwise, the number won't be accurate but I'd guess it should be OK.

Comment: @William: I've read the question several times, and it's *still* poorly written, and it *still* doesn't give a valid result for `c` if `a` and `b` are 0.01.

Comment: @William I assumed that rule #3 is only approximately true, i.e. that rounding is allowed. If ConvertABtoC rounds down A*B to 2 digits after the decimal, then this works.

Comment: please read again Jon, I wrote it clearer; hope it helps. @Jeffrey, Yes, rounding is allowed if it solves the problem. I think if after about 90-100 tries it didn't find the right partitions, then A*B will never give the same C as it may become 100.08 when rounded. If the partitions are found with less than 50 tries, the algorithm works well.

Comment: @Jon, your a= 0.01 and b=0.01 never happens. please read again the question. if c=0.01 then a = 1.00 and b = 0.10.

Comment: @William: So you *only* need a conversion one way? You keep telling me to read the question again, but it's *still* not clear. What about values of `c` such that there *is* no value of `a` and `b` where `c = a * b`? For example, take `c = 137.81`. What values of `a` and `b` would you want then? (13781 is prime, which is what causes the problem.) Are you now going to add the stipulation that if there's no valid combination of `a` and `b`, that value of `c` won't happen?

Comment: @William: Indeed, the example given in this answer of c=100.07 is another case where there's no a and b values giving exactly the right answer. You've said "I'd guess it should be OK" - but where's that in the question? You state: "you can use rounding if you'd need to as long as c = a * b" - but here `c` *doesn't* equal `a * b`.

Comment: @Jon, in that case as Jeffrey suggested, you'd find the 137.81 * 10000 + 1 = 1378101 and find primes from this number. if there is no a and b found with less than 10000 then you'd add 1 and try with 1378102 until you find a proper a and b. does it make sense? the problem here would be that it works accurately only with 50 or so tries.

Comment: @Jon, in the Jeffrey's example, the product of a and b would be 100.0701 and when rounded the original 100.07 is returned. right?

Comment: @Jeffrey, how would you write the logic to find out the partition 1 and 2?

Comment: @William: *When rounded* it returns 100.07, yes. But that's not what the rule states. If the rule stated `decimal.Round(a * b, 2) == c` that would be a different matter. I'm tempted to add an "answer" as a suggested rewording of the question, just temporarily. Then if you believe my restatement captures everything from your original question but in a clearer form, you could replace the question with it. Thoughts?

Comment: @William: But even with the change, I don't think the question has been written as clearly as it could be. Would you be interested in seeing my alternative formulation? Oh, and if there *is* an exact version, does that have to be used? For example, if c is 0, is a=0.01, b=0.01 a valid answer even though a=0, b=0 would be a more precise one?

Comment: @William: I've added another answer which restates the question in a simpler form (IMO) and demonstrates why it's *still* not possible for all values of `c` in the range.

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted my previous answer, as I don't believe it was helpful any more, as the question's changed so much over time.

Here's what I *understand* the question to be:

You are given an input (`c`) of type `decimal` such that:

- `0 <= c <= 99.99m * 99.99m`
- `c` has at most two decimal places (i.e. `c == decimal.Round(c, 2)`)

You are required to find to `decimal` values `a` and `b` such that:

- Each of `a` and `b` are in the range `[0, 99.99m]`
- Each of `a` and `b` have at most two decimal places
- `decimal.Round(a * b, 2) == c`

---

My answer is that it's *still* not possible for all values of `c`. Counterexample: `c = 9997.50`

The highest possible values of `a` and `b` (99.99m each) gives `decimal.Round(a * b, 2) == 9998.00`, so that fails with a product which is too high.

Now if you keep `a` as high as it can be, and reduce `b` as little as possible, we get `a=99.99m, b=99.98m` - and now `decimal.Round(a * b, 2) == 9997.00`, so that fails with a product which is too low.

There is no way of getting any product *between* those two values - we've perturbed our first attempt by as small an amount as possible. Therefore there are no values for `a` and `b` satisfying the problem.

(I'm anticipating a new rule being introduced to cope with this, as that seems to be the way this question is going...)

Answer (score 0):

Skeet's idea to treat the interval as itself * 100 makes everything so much clearer...

The problem is indeed without a complete solution. It asks you to create a bijective function f : A x B -> C,
where A = B = {0 ... 9999} and C = {0 ... 9999*9999 }

9999*9999 = 9998001; plus the 0, that gives a cardinality of 99,980,002.

A X B has a cardinality of 100,000,000.

A bijective function over finite sets can't be defined when the domain and codomain have different cardinalities. There will always be at most 19,998 values of c whose (a, b) breakdown will have more than one solution.

Going back on the original interval definition: the closest you can get to a proper function is something like:

```
public decimal Ab2C(decimal a, decimal b)
{
    if(a != 99.99 and a != 99.98)
        return a*100 + b;
    return (100-a)*100 + b; // for instance;
}
```

In this case, values for a between 0.02 to 99.97 will give unique results; a = 0.00 or 99.99 will be identical, likewise for a = 0.01 or 99.98. there is NO possible discrimination between these two values.

```
public void C2AB(decimal c, out decimal a, out decimal b)
{
    // todo: sanity checks.
    if (c <= 99.99)  // either a = 0.00, or a = 99.99; and b = c.
    {
        b = c;
        a = 0.00;
        return;
    }

    if (c <= 2*99.99)
    {
        b = c - 99.99;
        a = 0.01; // or 9.98.
        return;
    }
    a = c / 100;
    b = c % 100;
}
```

}

Comment: ok imagine you have multiplied it by 100 and have integer values now. how would you resolve it by integer values?

Comment: This is what I get if I don't follow Wiki links... what I wanted to say was already described in the article.