# How to find out the closest possible combination of some given prime numbers to 10000?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

```
public int Partition1 {get;set;}
public int Partition1 {get;set;}

private void SetPartitions(List<int> primeNumbers)
{       
    this.Partition1 = // get the product of the prime numbers closest to 10000
    this.Partition2 = // get the product of the remaining prime numbers            
}
```

SetPartitions method accepts an array of prime numbers such as 2, 3, 5, 2851, 13.

In the above example, it should assign:

```
this.Partition1 = 2851 * 3; // which is 8553 and closest possible to 10000
this.Partition2 = 2 * 5 * 13;
```

How to implement the logic?

Comment: nice question and just wonder where you will use that logic?

Comment: I'll use it for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985725/how-to-convert-2-restricted-decimal-variables-to-a-third-variable-and-vice-versa

Comment: @mekici at an interview, of course. Why ask something practical at an interview? Instead, ask [something useless]<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985725/how-to-convert-2-restricted-decimal-variables-to-a-third-variable-and-vice-versa> - then you can decide not to hire Jon Skeet because he tells you that there is no solution.

Comment: their product should be below 10000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then go through each number from 10,000 to 2. For each of these, test to see if the prime factorization of the number is a subset of the given list. If it is, then we have found the answer.

`Partition1` is the prime factors of the number. `Partition2` is simply `primeNumbers - Partition1`.

Here's the psuedocode:

```
for n=10000 to 2
    factors = prime_factorization(n)

    if( factors is subset primeNumbers ) {
        partition1 = factors
        partition2 = primeNumbers - factors
        return (partition1,partition2)
    }
```

Comment: I think your answer is true one but you should edit it to clarify it, if you do it I'll going to delete my answer, else I'll edit my answer :) in fact you should clarify what you mean by prime factorization. In fact it shouldn't be common factorization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How is prime factorization not clear? It's a grade-school level concept.

Comment: And if "closest to 10k" allows greater than 10k, with 10001 being closer than 9998, then the loop can run "for i = 0 to 10000: check(10000-i); check(10000+i)". And if you still haven't found Partition1 after that, then all the primes in the input are above 20000, so the solution is to take the smallest.

Comment: I understand that it works but wouldn't it be too slow? calculating prime, factors of each number from 10000 to 2?! is there any better performant algorithm?

Comment: @William: No, factoring small numbers is easy. You can do it by trial division in `O(sqrt(N))` time.

Comment: for example you have {2,2851} in your primes, so common prime factor gives 2^13 as closest possible but I think it's not so by OPs assumption, he just want current prime multiplication not nearest factor. So the factorization is not normal factorization.

Comment: A list of 13 twos is not a sublist of {2,2851}. I do not mean "set" in the strict mathematical sense of the word.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is below

```
private void SetPartitions(List<int> primeNumbers, int bound)
{
    int[] mods = new int[primeNumbers.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.Count; i++)
        mods[i] = bound % primeNumbers[i];

    int count = bound;
    do
    {
        int temp = count;

        for(int j = 0; j < mods.Length; j++)
            if(mods[j] == 0) 
                temp /= primeNumbers[j];

        if(temp == 1)
        {
            this.Partition1 = count;
            for(int k = 0; k < mods.Length; k++)
                if(mods[k] != 0)
                    temp *= primeNumbers[k];
            this.Partition2 = temp;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < mods.Length; k++)
                mods[k] = (mods[k] == 0) ? primeNumbers[k] - 1 : mods[k] - 1;
            count--;
        }
    }while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is homework. The answer is 2 * 4999 (9998), by inspection.

The brute force technique is (should be) obvious. Take a list of all primes x such that 0 <= x <= 5000 (since you're looking for factors here, you'll be multiplying numbers...and since the smallest prime is 2, you don't need to worry about anything larger than 5000). for each item  xin the list, iterate over the list again examining each y in the list. Multiply them together and record the delta between the product and 10000. Keep the smallest one.

Another way of doing it would be to start with 10000 and compute its prime factors (if any).

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorization.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorizationAlgorithms.html

For instance:

```
int i = 10000 ;
int[] primeFactors = null ;
while ( i > 0 && ( primeFactors == null || primeFactors.Length == 0 ) )
{
  primeFactors = ComputePrimeFactorsOf( i ) ;
}
// if primeFactors is contains data, there's your solution
```

Comment: Good answer but I believe question relates to 'some', not 'all', prime numbers. i.e. method will be supplied a list of prime numbers - compute the product closest to 10000 given that list.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a reformulation of [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). While yours is multiplicative calculating the logarithm of the primes and the target number transforms it into an additive problem.

But even if the general Knapsack problem is *hard*, your particular subset of problems might have a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `2^14 = 16384`, you can have at most 13 prime factors, of which at most 5 can be distinct (because `2*3*5*7*11*13 = 30030 > 10000`). The simplest solution is to iterate over all combinations. If you want one of the products to be the closest to 10,000, then you go through everything. If you only want one in which both partitions' product is less than 10,000, you can stop as soon as you have a solution. Even with no optimization at all, this should only take a fraction of a second on today's machines.

Comment: how would you write the logic for it?

Comment: Since we can have at most 5 distinct prime factors, I would use 5 nested loops that count up to the # of occurrances of each factor. You can bail out early if the current product is too large. If you have less than 5 distinct factors, I'd use a factor of 1 with a count of 1 to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
 internal static void GetPartitionsClosestTo9999(List<long> primeFactors, out long partition1, out long partition2)
        {
            for (var index = 9999; index >= 2; index--)
            {
                var primeFactorsForCurrentIndex = GetPrimeFactors(index);
                var isSubset = IsSubSet(primeFactorsForCurrentIndex, primeFactors); //!primeFactorsForCurrentIndex.Except(primeFactors).Any();
                if (isSubset)
                {
                    partition1 = index;
                    foreach (var primeFactorForCurrentIndex in primeFactorsForCurrentIndex)
                    {
                        primeFactors.Remove(primeFactorForCurrentIndex);
                    }
                    partition2 = GetProduct(primeFactors);
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new ApplicationException("No subset found.");
        }

        static bool IsSubSet<T>(ICollection<T> set, IEnumerable<T> toCheck)
        {
            return set.Count == (toCheck.Intersect(set)).Count();
        }
```